# How can I find out if an update cause a change in SQLITE with Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this code;

```
sql = "UPDATE SCORE SET A = 1 WHERE ID = 12 AND COUNT = 25";
db2.Execute(sql);
```

Is there a way that I can execute this kind of statement and find out if the update actually found and updated a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execute method returns the number of rows modified. So

```
var rowsModified = db2.Execute(sql);
if(rowsModified > 0)
{
    // the statement found at least one row to update
}
```

Modified means in this case that a row to update was found. So, it is counted as a modification even when the statement results in assigning the same values already present in the row.